# Which HornetQ libraries i need for JMS client?

Tags: spring, jms, hornetq

I have a standalone hornetq server and a *JMS client* working with it! With respect to hornetq user-manual i should only add *jnp-client.jar* and *jms.jar* to client classpath. But when i trying use hornetq server (produce and consume messages), several ClassNotFoundExceptions thrown, so i forced adding these jar files to my client classpath:

*1. jms
 2. jnp-client* 
 3. hornetq-jms-client 
 4. netty 
 5. hornetq-core-cilent 
 6. jboss-common

Am i using *Hornetq core client* instead of *jms client*?? What jar files i really need for *jms client*??

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- JndiTemplate -->
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<!-- Connection Factory -->
<bean id="hornetqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Destionation -->
<bean id="annotationDeleteCommandDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="/queue/command/annotation/deleteQueue" />
</bean>

<!-- Message Listener -->
<bean id="annotationMessageHandler" class="command.messaging.handler.annotation.AnnotationMessageHandler">
        <property name="annotationService" ref="annotationService"/>
</bean>

<!-- Message Listener Container -->
<bean id="annotationDeleteCommandMsgListenerContainer"
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" 
      p:connectionFactory-ref="hornetqConnectionFactory"
      p:destination-ref="annotationDeleteCommandDestination"
      p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER"
      p:messageListener-ref="annotationDeleteCommandMessageHandler"
      p:concurrentConsumers="10"
      p:maxConcurrentConsumers="50"
      p:receiveTimeout="5000"
      p:idleTaskExecutionLimit="10
      p:idleConsumerLimit="5" />

<!-- Message Producer -->
<bean id="messageSender" class="command.messaging.sender.MessageSender">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="hornetqConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

HornetQ-JMS-Client is an adapter for the HornetQ-Core-Client that exposes the JMS API. 
So you need them both.

And HornetQ-Core-Client needs netty internally, so you need that one, too.

Not sure about jboss-common. You need some logging dependency, but I don't remember exactly which one.

Please note that, unlike SOAP, JMS is an API, not a protocol. The rest of the application is independent of the API provider, but you need the correct client libraries that understand the custom protocol that your JMS Server uses. So you can't use the HornetQ JMS Client to connect to ActiveMQ, for example.

Comment: You won't need jboss-loggins on the client unless you want to have logging configuration on the client ala jboss style.

Comment: also he's using spring.. I'm not sure what dependencies he will need from spring.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs...

If you are using just a pure HornetQ Core client (i.e. no JMS) then you need hornetq-core-client.jar, hornetq-commons.jar, and netty.jar.

If you are using JMS on the client side, then you will also need to include hornetq-jms-client.jar and jboss-jms-api.jar.

These refer to files in the standalone hornetq download's lib directory.

I needed to add jnp-client.jar to avoid a CNF too.